# Checkio. Как итерировать тип данных set. Суффикс или Совпадение

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Дан набор слов в нижнем регистре. Проверьте есть ли в этом наборе пара
>   слов, такая что одно слово заканчивается другим (суффикс или
>   совпадение).
>
> Для примера: {"hi", "hello", "lo"} -- "lo" это окончание "hello", так
>   что результат True.

```
def checkio(words_set):
    for w1 in words_set:
        for w2 in words_set:
            #как тут использовать .endswith()?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert checkio({"hello", "lo", "he"}) == True, "helLO"
    assert checkio({"hello", "la", "hellow", "cow"}) == False, "hellow la cow"
    assert checkio({"walk", "duckwalk"}) == True, "duck to walk"
    assert checkio({"one"}) == False, "Only One"
    assert checkio({"helicopter", "li", "he"}) == False, "Only end"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def checkio(words_set):
for w1 in words_set:
    for w2 in words_set:
        if w1.endswith(w2):
            if w1 != w2:
                return True
return False
```